# check cell content is substring of inputted string on screen ( include backspace ) - python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a substring "Apple on the desk" on column of excel file... I want to check a string when user input on screen. If content on column of excel file is substring, then return result is correct.

Ex: when user input 'I have an apple on the desk'... the screen will print 'correct'

I have below code... But how to include backspace while checking str ?? I do not want to spit backspace out of str.

```
path_to_csv_file = 'C:\\excel.xlsx'
code_names_dataframe = pd.read_excel(path_to_csv_file) 
code_names_dictionary = code_names_dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')
excel = input('You: ')
excelanswer = None
excelword = excel.split(' ')
excelmatch = code_names_dataframe['EXCEL'].isin(excelword)
  if excelmatch.any():
    excelanswer = code_names_dataframe[excelmatch]['EXCELANSWER'].iloc[0]
    print('ChatBot:', excelanswer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :

```
excelmatch = code_names_dataframe['EXCEL'].isin(excelword)
```

**With:**

```
excelmatch = code_names_dataframe['EXCEL'].apply(lambda x: True if x.lower() in excel.lower() else False)
```